# Actionscript randomly distribute objects on stage

Tags: actionscript, random, stage

I'm trying to distribute 3 objects randomly on my stage but it's not working. My movie is 800x800.

```
function makeRock():void{
    var tempRock:MovieClip;

    for(var i:Number = 1; i < 3; i++){
        tempRock = new Rock();
        tempRock.x = Math.round(800);
        tempRock.y = Math.round(-800);
        addChild(tempRock);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `Math.round(800);` with `Math.random()*800;`

```
function makeRock():void
{
    var tempRock:MovieClip;

    var i:uint = 0;
    for(i; i < 3; i++)
    {
        tempRock = new Rock();

        tempRock.x = Math.random()*800;
        tempRock.y = Math.random()*800;

        addChild(tempRock);
    }
}
```

`Math.round(800)` is just returning 800.

`Math.random()` returns a random number between 0 and 1, which you can multiply by 800 to get a random result of 0-800. A good note to make is that `Math.random()` never actually returns 1.0. Just everything from 0 **up to** 1.

---

**Further reading:**

As a side note: this makes it simple to return a random element from an array; because you're never getting 1 you can cast the result of `Math.random()*array.length` to `uint()` and always be within the boundaries of the array length.

eg.

```
var ar:Array = [1,2,"hello",4,5,6,7,8,9,0];

var randomElement:Object = ar[uint(Math.random()*ar.length)];
trace(randomElement);
```

Comment: Haha no problems - you don't even want to know some of the no-brainers I've done in my experience.

Comment: Your array solution is actually a bit flawed, I think. Making it a uint it will never return ar[0]. It should actually be ar[Math.floor((Math.random()*ar.length))];

Comment: No.. uint just chops off everything after the decimal point. Run this and see: for(var i:uint=0; i<1000; i++) trace(uint(Math.random()*4));